# HTML open in IE6,8,9,10 and all other browser but not in IE7 in windows 7 64 bit machine's IETester

Tags: html

I have a strange problem in my machine, my html pages are all opens in IE6,8,9 and 10 in my machine which installed XP but on another machine which I have Windows 7 64 bit OS those HTML pages are not working on IE7. I am using IETester for checking compatibility test.

I can't understand what's the actual problem is, please help.

Comment: ...pages are not working...it depends on what you mean! What kind of errors? scripts? layout?

Comment: Is there a console window? check there! Or install (find...) a true IE7 for your tests (and check its console window for errors). No error, no solution! :)

Comment: I did not find a console window in IETester, any suggestion how to get the error,IE9 is my default browser..

Comment: Thanks Adriano,
I got my answer here

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_other/i-need-to-run-ie7-on-a-system-runningwindows-7/3134ba08-819e-4038-b68c-73f7a3e14b8a

Comment: Not really! If you change your UserAgent string you do not set-up IE to render as IE7! It's a better test to use IE9 and set document mode and rendering mode to IE7 but...don't think it's **really** like IE7!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's ietest bug;If you want you open your file eg: `E:\test\test.html`,you must type `E:\test` in ietester Ie7 tab adressbar and push "Enter",and it will show all your file in E:\test, and you type `E:\test\test.html` in adressbar and push "Enter", and it will open.

And I never test IE7 in IEtester,IE has a devTool ,you just push "F12",just like firebug,it will show.It has IE 7 8 9 modo ,but except IE6.